# Group by and getting min and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @dCurrentDate Date = CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())

Declare @dNextDate Date = DATEADD(month,1,CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()))
```

I created a table which contains 10 employee Ids and name as @tbl

then i wrote a query to select min and max date of employee for next 30 days.

```
  SELECT 
         c.fkEmployeeId as Employee, 
         e.FullName,c.calendarday 
    FROM  
         EmployeeCalendar c 
                            JOIN Employee e 
                                  ON (e.pkEmployeeId=c.fkEmployeeId) 
GROUP BY c.fkEmployeeId,
         e.FullName,
         c.calendarday
  HAVING 
         c.CalendarDay BETWEEN @dCurrentDate AND @dNextDate 
     AND c.fkEmployeeId IN (
                            SELECT
                                   EmployeeId 
                              FROM
                                   @tbl
                           )
```

i am getting result

```
Id  |   Name                   |  Date 
76      Muhammad                  2014-03-05
76      Muhammad                  2014-03-12
594     Khan                      2014-02-14
```

but i need

```
    Id    |   Name           | min_date      | max_date
    76        muhammad         2014-03-05      2014-03-12
   594        khan             2014-02-14      2014-02-14
```

how can i get this.

Comment: there is no field names in this above query like min_record_date, max_record_date??

Comment: i said i have a data like this.

Comment: what happens if you'll remove `c.calendarday` from your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: it says employeecalendar is invalid because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @wqrahd [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) and then post your table structure

Comment: Why you have created a table with name @tbl, as you said. It has a different meaning. change it to tbl.

Comment: i have created a temp table. "declare @tbl Table(EmployeeId int)".it is a code of store procedure.

Comment: and by the way . i have already done what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MIN(record_date), MAX(record_date) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Comment: i need a filter on date . mean i need records which lies between todays date and the next 30 dates.

Comment: I answered your question. You should reconsider your question if this answer does not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT id, 
         MIN(record_date) AS min_record_date, 
         MAN(record_date) AS max_record_date 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: i need a filter on date . mean i need records which lies between todays date and the next 30 dates.

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
    DECLARE @dCurrentDate DATE = CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE ()) 
DECLARE @dNextDate 
DATE = DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE ())) 
SELECT 
  c.fkEmployeeId AS Employee,
  e.FullName, MIN(c.calendarday),MAX(c.calendarday) 
FROM
  EmployeeCalendar c 
  JOIN Employee e 
    ON (e.pkEmployeeId = c.fkEmployeeId) 
GROUP BY c.fkEmployeeId
HAVING c.CalendarDay BETWEEN @dCurrentDate 
  AND @dNextDate 
  AND c.fkEmployeeId IN 
  (SELECT 
    EmployeeId 
  FROM
    @tbl)
```

Comment: it says calenday day is invalid in having clause

Comment: it shows error : 'CalendarDay' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT id,Name 
MIN(record_date) AS min_date, 
MAN(record_date) AS max_date 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id,Name
ORDER BY id
```